# dmesg with / without sudo on Debian / Mint

Tags: debian, linux-mint, dmesg

I noticed this difference some time ago, but until now, I didn't bother to ask, why is that?

On Linux Mint 18 (Ubuntu-based) I can run `dmesg` without using `sudo`.

On GNU/Linux Debian 9 I must use sudo in order to use for example `dmesg`.

I wonder, where is this behavior coded? And can it be changed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is controlled by the `dmesg_restrict` `sysctl` entry, documented in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html#dmesg-restrict). Its default value is determined by the `CONFIG_SECURITY_DMESG_RESTRICT` kernel configuration value, which is typically enabled in modern distributions.

You can see the current value by running

```
/sbin/sysctl kernel.dmesg_restrict
```

and change its value using (as `root`)

```
sysctl -w kernel.dmesg_restrict=1
```

(to enable the restriction) or

```
sysctl -w kernel.dmesg_restrict=0
```

(to disable it and restore the old behaviour).

To make this change permanent (automatically applied at boot), write it to `/etc/sysctl.conf` or a configuration file under `/etc/sysctl.d`:

```
echo kernel.dmesg_restrict=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/99-dmesg.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the default kernel config of newer kernels: `CONFIG_SECURITY_DMESG_RESTRICT=y`

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered you can use `/sbin/sysctl` to inspect and change values at runtime.

However, to make these changes persistent across reboots you should add them to `/etc/sysctl.conf`